# VBA to VBS for ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to convert some VBA code that I embed in Excel spreadsheets to save all tabs as CSVs into a VBS script that I can run from command line to do the same thing.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
Dim worksheetCount
workSheetCount = oExcel.Worksheets.Count
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim counter
Dim currentWorkSheet
For counter = 1 to workSheetCount
    Set currentWorkSheet = oBook.Worksheets(counter)
    currentWorkSheet.Copy
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs oBook & "-" & currentWorkSheet.Name & ".csv", 6
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next    
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

The error occurs at the beginning of line "oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs" and says object doesn't support this method. So I assume the Excel object doesn't have the ActiveWorkbook method? Is there a VBA->VBS conversion here, some other method I should be using?

**EDIT**

This works for me now:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim strCurDir
strCurDir = WshShell.CurrentDirectory & "\" & oBook.Name & "-"

Dim worksheetCount
workSheetCount = oExcel.Worksheets.Count

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim counter
Dim currentWorkSheet
For counter = 1 to workSheetCount
    Set currentWorkSheet = oBook.Worksheets(counter)
    currentWorkSheet.Copy
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strCurDir & currentWorkSheet.Name & ".csv", 6
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: `oBook` is a workbook - so the problem is `oBook & "-" & currentWorkSheet.Name & ".csv"`. `oBook.Name` maybe? You can't concatenate a workbook...

Comment: @GeertBellekens OP does need to reference the active workbook, as `currentWorksheet.Copy` creates a new book.

Comment: You have to be extremely careful when you start using things like `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`.. specially in a script. I would highly recommend that rather than using that, qualify your sheets and then reference them

Comment: @BigBen Indeed it does, never occurred to me that it would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `ActiveWorkbook`. The problem is that you are not specifying a complete path.

Specify a path and it will work. For example

```
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\MyFolder\" & _
oBook.Name & "-" & currentWorkSheet.Name & ".csv", 6
```

You will get next error on `ThisWorkbook.Activate`. Fully qualify it and it will work.

**TIP**

You may want to remove the file extension and then save the file ;) Something like this

```
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\MyFolder\" & _
Left(oBook.Name, (InStrRev(oBook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) & _
"-" & currentWorkSheet.Name & ".csv", 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the worksheet using the index number, or do a for each loop, where the each item is `each wksh in workbook.worksheets`.
Also, I moved the worksheet.close method to after the for loop, because it would close out your workbook before you were finished

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
Dim worksheetCount
workSheetCount = oExcel.Worksheets.Count
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim counter
Dim currentWorkSheet
For counter = 1 to workSheetCount
Set currentWorkSheet = oBook.Worksheets(counter)
    currentWorkSheet.Copy
    oExcel.Worksheets(counter).SaveAs oBook & "-" & currentWorkSheet.Name & ".csv", 6
    'ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next
oExcel.Worksheets(counter).Close False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```